# Ubuntu 20.04 out of memory after using it for one year

Tags: boot, 20.04

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 for long days. I use Ubuntu beside Windows. Suddenly one month ago, when I tried to open Ubuntu, it says  error :out of memory, press any key to continue. When I press any key, something gets opened (2nd image). My GNU GRUBLOADER version is 2.06.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Image backup link :')
[1st]   https://ibb.co/kKBJ62H
[2nd]  https://ibb.co/KyxHfLh

Comment: Probably your motherboard is Dead. The Power-On Self Test can't see your RAM, can't access the disk. Have you vibrated your hardware recently? See `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI`

Comment: I'm using Windows 11 with this PC. It's motherboard is working well.